# How Can I store the 2D Rotation in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, transform

I need to rotate the wheel from the previous position. But it resets every time Screen is touched. The problem occurs when the touch is ended(Released) and then again Touched.

I need to store the Rotation value of the object.

Any Help is appreciated. Thanks

---

[Video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M-2DlZunlBXjugkThxWYF-tqviuB-G53)

---

```
direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position) - transform.position;
  angle = (Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg)-90;
  rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
  transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
  oldRotation = transform.rotation;
```

Comment: Could your add the rest of your code for context? Especially when the problem lies in your handling the touches e.g. the part where the touches are handled would be helpful ...

Answer (score 0):

What event is that function in? An update one?
Quite likely it is executed at least once after the finger is released and at that point, touch.position doesn't have a valid value anymore.
Check first that the user is actually touching and execute the code only if that is the case.

Comment: It's inside Update and on TouchPhase.Moved